# Laravel time 24h format regex error (No ending delimiter)

Tags: php, regex, laravel

So I have this:

```
'title' => 'required|max:100|regex:/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$/',
'start_time' => 'date_format:H:i|regex:/^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])?)$/',
```

title is working perfect (the user has to enter at least 1 letter)
But I'm having problems with start_time which is returning

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found", exception:
>   "ErrorException",…}

What I want is to validate 24h format with the possibility that the user ads AM or PM, for example: 05:10 PM, so I want to validate the first 5 characters and free the rest, I think it's correct.

So, what am I missing to make it run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule is well done **BUT** you need to know, specify validation rules with regex separated by pipeline **can lead** to undesired behavior.

The proper way to define a validation rule should be:

```
'title' => 'required|max:100|regex:/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$/',
'start_time' => ['date_format:H:i','regex:/^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])?)$/'],
```

You can read on the official docs:

> regex:pattern
>
> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be **necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters**, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex

Comment: thank you! And why don't you add it as well in title? I wonder why is workig without array

Comment: That is because in start_time you are using pipeline symbol in regex. And laravel validation take it as a separate validation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'start_time' => ['date_format:H:i', 'regex:/^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])?)$/'],
```

The problem is the `|` character in the regular expression. Laravel uses it as a separator between rules.

Answer (score 2):

The character pipe `|` in regex conflicts with `|` in seprating rules. You have to initialize an array:

```
'start_time' => ['date_format:H:i', 'regex:/^((([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])?)$/']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, you just miss the last comma. But the question now is, why is it working with title without array?

Comment: Because there is no pipe in its regex. You only have to put rules into an array when your regex contains a `|`.

Comment: OIC! Thank you!